# Image processing for automatic defect detection in product

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

What are the steps required to implement automatic defect detection using image processing? 
What are the best open source and commercial softwares available to implement a solution?
Kindly suggest your ideas.

Comment: This kind of question is off-topic unfortunately.  Voting to close.

Comment: Hi @rayryeng, May I know why it is off-topic. This forum is to discuss on any technical difficulties we face. Here I would like to know the different approaches that can solve my problem. And also I found many softwares on internet, So I asked people to suggest better one if they have used already.

Comment: Point #4 - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic... *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*  BTW, StackOverflow is **not** a forum.  It is a question-and-answer site, which functions differently than a forum - http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Sorry @rayryeng. I didn't know about this rules of asking questions. I'll keep it in mind for future. Thanks.

Comment: No worries.  Yeah keep that in mind when asking questions next time... but for what it's worth, I agree with the accepted answer.  Go with OpenCV!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resource is OpenCV. Get the new one.

The specific features needing detection will depend on your product, but there is no better starting point.

My suspicion, without knowing more about your product, will be that you need lots of pictures of good and bad products, which you can label good/bad as a dataset in OpenCV.

Comment: Is it just about training with genuine and defected product and classify the input image. Or any preprocessing required before input to classification system.

Comment: Look at the classifier system in the OpenCV docs. You will need a few hundred sample images to build a HAAR-style classifier. For example, if you have lots of pictures of good and bad bolts, you give them all to the classifier and label them as good or bad. The HAAR classifier, once trained, will be able to look at novel pictures and give a good estimation as to whether the new image is of a good or bad bolt.